# Was there a way to prevent Morinth from turning into a Banshee?

Tags: mass-effect-3

With her dying breath, Samara did warn me that I'll someday regret my choice, but I certainly wasn't expecting this:

[image]

Now I'm wondering if it was something I may have missed that resulted in her banshification since I sort of rushed through the last quarter of the game.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't stop it, but no proof, coz I've never killed Samara (although I plan on it in my "Try to kill as many ME2 characters as possible" run).

Comment: @MrSmooth hah, that was this playthrough I imported, the only survivors of the mission was morinth and zaeed

Comment: (SPOILERS) I'll probably let Tali survive, so that she can die in ME3 in the geth mission

Comment: @MrSmooth nice planning there, suitably evil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately no :/ ,
according [Wikia](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Morinth) there is no way to prevent to turn her into a banshee.

Or in a way there is one option, but that implies killing her in Mass effect 2.... Probably not what you are looking for.

Comment: that's a shame...